# if condition resulting in The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am using if condition in python to perform a calculation but I am getting The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). error

Can someone please help me in understanding how to perform actions on a dataframe based on **if condition** on other columns?

```
if (simulated_hour['Weeknnd'] == 'Weekday'):
    simulated_hour['simulated'] = simulated_hour['Forecast_call']*simulation_weekday
    simulated_hour
```

Attached is the image of the code and error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the following code snippet:

```
simulated_hour.loc[simulated_hour['Weeknnd'] == 'Weekday', 'simulated'] = simulated_hour.loc[simulated_hour['Weeknnd'] == 'Weekday', 'Forecast_call']*simulation_weekday
```

Pandas has it's own query syntax, since you can't use simple `if` statements to make selections like you've mentioned.

If you're familiar with SQL, the following state could be helpful in understanding the basis: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html

Answer (score 2):

The message if self-explanatory. Since `simulated_hour['Weeknnd']` **is not a single value**, the term `simulated_hour['Weeknnd'] == 'Weekday'` might be true for some values and false for others. So, use `(...).any()` or `(...).all()` depending on whether you want at least one or all of the values to be true.